# How to determine if dropdown is collapsed?

Tags: c#, html, css, unit-testing, selenium

I'm trying to automate some of my tests using Selenium and I have this painInTheA... issue. The flow is like this:

1. Select option from dropdown
2. Click Search button just below the dropdown (it is "behind" the dropdown
   when it's expanded)

Unfortunately, Selenium is faster than the animation. It selects the option and try to click the search button when it's still under the expanded list (tho, it's collapsing at the moment).

For the moment I use nasty hack which is to wait 1 second before clicking.

**Is there any way to determine, if the dropdown is collapsed so we are able to click the button without any problems?**

HTML code for the dropdown is like this:

```
<select data-bind="value: SearchCriteriaContacts.IsActive, options: YesNo, optionsText: 'ItemValue', optionsValue: 'ItemId', optionsCaption: $root.AnyText">
<option value="">--- Any ---</option>
<option value="">Yes</option>
<option value="">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explicit wait to wait for the button to be visiable

> C# code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By locator, string searchButtonLocator)).Click();
```

This will wait up to 15 seconds for the butto to be visiable.

For more ExpectedConditions look [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)